# Creating a thread to run a piece of code?

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm new to android development and I want to create a button to start a tempo beats (like metronome) and stop when clicked again (one button for both start and stop).

When I click the button it starts playing 5 sounds one after another in one second delay and repeating that 5 sounds loop until I press the button again to stop.

My issue is that the whole system is kind of "locked" until all the 5 sounds played (can't press volume up or down and the stop button actually works only after the 5 sounds finished).

So I want to create a thread in order to run the 5 sounds and when I press the button again, I want the thread to stop immediately. I tried without success, so any help would be great.

Here is the onClick method:

```
public boolean tempoOn = false; // global

public void clickHandlerStartTempo(View view) {
    if (!tempoOn) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start Tempo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        tempoOn = true;
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final int delay = 1000; //milliseconds

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                if (tempoOn) {
                    playSound(0);
                    SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                    playSound(1);
                    SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                    playSound(1);
                    SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                    playSound(1);
                    SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                    playSound(1);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
                }
            }
        }, delay);
    } else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop Tempo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        tempoOn = false;
    }

}
```

the playSound method (I'm using SoundPool):

```
public void playSound(int fileNumber) {
    sounds.play(soundIds.get(fileNumber), 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1);
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't need to create a thread to play your audio. MediaPlayer object does it for you. Post your code for playSound() so that I can get a better idea

Comment: @nupadhyaya Updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to run something on background please check the term 'AsyncTask'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the media player as a service to run in background. Try looking at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer#java "Using MediaPlayer in a service"